# What is the most efficient way to construct large block matrices in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

Inspired by Mike Bantegui's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853928/more-efficient-way-of-calculating-this-recurrence-relation-in-mathematica) on constructing a matrix defined as a recurrence relation, I wonder if there is any general guidance that could be given on setting up large block matrices in the least computation time. In my experience, constructing the blocks and then putting them together can be quite inefficient (thus my answer was actually slower than Mike's original code). `Join` and possibly `ArrayFlatten` are possibly less efficient than they could be.

Obviously if the matrix is sparse, one can use `SparseMatrix` constructs, but there will be times when the block matrix you are constructing is not sparse.

What is best practice for this kind of problem? I am assuming the elements of the matrix are numeric.

Comment: just using `Do` loops and compiling can be quite fast, especially in version 8 which gives the option of compiling to C. But I have little experience of this so can't offer general opinions

Comment: I have to agree with acl here. The naive `Do` loop was actually faster than the functional version, especially for large matrix sizes. When compiled, the `Do` loop became significantly faster. One interesting thing was the fact that something along the lines of `a + b`, where a and b were matrices, was really slow.

Comment: Yes, this is why I posed the question. Long-time Mathematica users have all been brought up to "say no to loops", and the idea that functional programming styles were more efficient in Mathematica. This was the stock response when people complained that Mma was slower than Matlab. But if things have changed over recent versions, I thought it worthwhile documenting that.

Comment: @Verbeia: I agree. My answer actually has some rather interesting examples of how this plays out. None of the examples I used below were arbitrary toy examples. All of them are used in my production code for some rather long and expensive calculations.

Comment: I discussed one example that might be of interest to you in my book, here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node553.html (The introduction is alas missing in the web version, but it is present in the pdf). I was generating block random matrices with a certain symmetry, and in that example I compared different techniques for doing that. The problem however was a bit different: each matrix in my case was not necessarily very large, but I had to generate a large number of them. Also, I did it in M5-M6, long before the things like compilation to C became available.

Comment: @verbeia it's true that generally functional code in mathematica is faster than procedural, because you push things into the kernel (as I think Leonid nicely expresses it). But if you have to then recover pieces back up to the "user" level and then pass to another function, it can become very expensive. In addition, if there are Do loops with very expensive operations inside, changing to functional forms will not affect much because the extra cost of the Do loop is clearly negligible. Compilation (perhaps automatic) might of course make a difference.

Comment: There is nothing to prevent one from using SparseArray operations to build the matrix,even if it is not 'sparse'. You could also use Normal[] on the result to convert it to non-sparse.

Comment: @Nasser That is true, and I often use it. But I don't think it is particularly fast (although I do not remember how much I tested it, so maybe it is...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The code shown below is available here: http://pastebin.com/4PWWxGhB. Just copy and paste it into a notebook to test it out.**

I was actually trying to do several functional ways of calculating matrices, since I
figured the functional way (which is typically idiomatic in Mathematica) is more efficient.

As one example, I had this matrix which was composed of two lists:

```
In: L = 1200;
e = Table[..., {2L}];
f = Table[..., {2L}];

h = Table[0, {2L}, {2L}];
Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i]], {i, 1, L}];
Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i-L]], {i, L+1, 2L}];
Do[h[[i, j]] = f[[i]]f[[j-L]], {i, 1, L}, {j, L+1, 2L}];
Do[h[[i, j]] = h[[j, i]], {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}];
```

My first step was to time everything.

```
In: h = Table[0, {2 L}, {2 L}];
AbsoluteTiming[Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i]], {i, 1, L}];]
AbsoluteTiming[Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i - L]], {i, L + 1, 2 L}];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 Do[h[[i, j]] = f[[i]] f[[j - L]], {i, 1, L}, {j, L + 1, 2 L}];]
AbsoluteTiming[Do[h[[i, j]] = h[[j, i]], {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}];]

Out: {0.0020001, Null}
{0.0030002, Null}
{5.0012861, Null}
{4.0622324, Null}
```

`DiagonalMatrix[...]` was slower than the do loops, so I decided to just use `Do` loops on the last step. As you can see, using `Outer[Times, f, f]` was much faster in this case.

I then wrote the equivalent using `Outer` for the blocks in the upper right and bottom left of the matrix, and `DiagonalMatrix` for the diagonal:

```
AbsoluteTiming[h1 = ArrayPad[Outer[Times, f, f], {{0, L}, {L, 0}}];]
AbsoluteTiming[h1 += Transpose[h1];]
AbsoluteTiming[h1 += DiagonalMatrix[Join[e, e]];]


Out: {0.9960570, Null}
{0.3770216, Null}
{0.0160009, Null}
```

The `DiagonalMatrix` was actually slower. I could replace this with just the `Do` loops, but I kept it because it was cleaner looking.

The current tally is 9.06 seconds for the naive `Do` loop, and 1.389 seconds for my next version using `Outer` and `DiagonalMatrix`. About a 6.5 times speedup, not too bad.

---

Sounds a lot faster, now doesn't it? Let's try using `Compile` now.

```
In: cf = Compile[{{L, _Integer}, {e, _Real, 1}, {f, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{h},
    h = Table[0.0, {2 L}, {2 L}];
    Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i]], {i, 1, L}];
    Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i - L]], {i, L + 1, 2 L}];
    Do[h[[i, j]] = f[[i]] f[[j - L]], {i, 1, L}, {j, L + 1, 2 L}];
    Do[h[[i, j]] = h[[j, i]], {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}];
    h]];

AbsoluteTiming[cf[L, e, f];]

Out: {0.3940225, Null}
```

Now it's running 3.56 times faster than my last version, and 23.23 times faster than the first one. Next version:

```
In: cf = Compile[{{L, _Integer}, {e, _Real, 1}, {f, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{h},
    h = Table[0.0, {2 L}, {2 L}];
    Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i]], {i, 1, L}];
    Do[h[[i, i]] = e[[i - L]], {i, L + 1, 2 L}];
    Do[h[[i, j]] = f[[i]] f[[j - L]], {i, 1, L}, {j, L + 1, 2 L}];
    Do[h[[i, j]] = h[[j, i]], {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}];
    h], CompilationTarget->"C", RuntimeOptions->"Speed"];

AbsoluteTiming[cf[L, e, f];]

Out: {0.1370079, Null}
```

Most of the speed came from `CompilationTarget->"C"`. Here I got another 2.84 speedup over the fastest version, and 66.13 times speedup over the first version. But all I did was just compile it!

Now, this is a very simple example. But this is real code I'm using to solve a problem in condensed matter physics. So don't dismiss it as possibly being a "toy example."

---

How's about another example of a technique we can use? I have a relatively simple matrix I have to build up. I have a matrix that's composed of nothing but ones from the start to some arbitrary point. The naive way may look something like this:

```
In: k = L;
AbsoluteTiming[p = Table[If[i == j && j <= k, 1, 0], {i, 2L}, {j, 2L}];]
Out: {5.5393168, Null}
```

Instead, let's build it up using `ArrayPad` and `IdentityMatrix`:

```
In: AbsoluteTiming[ArrayPad[IdentityMatrix[k], {{0, 2L-k}, {0, 2L-k}}
Out: {0.0140008, Null}
```

This actually doesn't work for k = 0, but you can special case that if you need that. Furthermore, depending on the size of k, this can be faster or slower. It's always faster than the Table[...] version though.

You could even write this using `SparseArray`:

```
In: AbsoluteTiming[SparseArray[{i_, i_} /; i <= k -> 1, {2 L, 2 L}];]
Out: {0.0040002, Null}
```

I could go on about some other things, but I'm afraid if I do I'll make this answer unreasonably large. I've accumulated a number of techniques for forming these various matrices and lists in the time I spent trying to optimize some code. The base code I worked with took over 6 days for one calculation to run, and now it takes only 6 hours to do the same thing.

I'll see if I can pick out the general techniques I've come up with and just stick them in a notebook to use.

**TL;DR: It seems like for these cases, the functional way outperforms the procedural way. But when compiled, the procedural code outperforms the functional code.**

Answer (score 4):

Looking at what `Compile` does to `Do` loops is instructive. Consider this:

```
L=1200;
Do[.7, {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}] // Timing
Do[.3 + .4, {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}] // Timing
Do[.3 + .4 + .5, {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}] // Timing
Do[.3 + .4 + .5 + .8, {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}] // Timing 
(*
{0.390163, Null}
{1.04115, Null}
{1.95333, Null}
{2.42332, Null}
*)
```

First, it seems safe to assume that `Do` does not automatically compile its argument if it's over some length (as `Map`, `Nest` etc do): you can keep adding constants and the derivative of time taken vs number of constants is constant. This is further supported by the nonexistence of such an option in `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]`.

Next, since this loops around `n(n-1)/2` times with `n=2*L`, so around 3*10^6 times for our `L=1200`, the time taken for each addition indicates that there is a lot more going on than is necessary.

Next let us try

```
Compile[{{L,_Integer}},Do[.7,{i,1,2 L},{j,1,i}]]@1200//Timing
Compile[{{L,_Integer}},Do[.7+.7,{i,1,2 L},{j,1,i}]]@1200//Timing
Compile[{{L,_Integer}},Do[.7+.7+.7+.7,{i,1,2 L},{j,1,i}]]@1200//Timing
(*
{0.032081, Null}
{0.032857, Null}
{0.032254, Null}
*)
```

So here things are more reasonable. Let's take a look:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
f1 = Compile[{{L, _Integer}}, 
   Do[.7 + .7 + .7 + .7, {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}]];
f2 = Compile[{{L, _Integer}}, Do[2.8, {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}]];
CompilePrint[f1]
CompilePrint[f2]
```

the two `CompilePrint`s give the same output, namely,

```
        1 argument
        9 Integer registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I5 = 0
        I2 = 2
        I1 = 1
        Result = V255

    1   I4 = I2 * I0
    2   I6 = I5
    3   goto 8
    4   I7 = I6
    5   I8 = I5
    6   goto 7
    7   if[ ++ I8 < I7] goto 7
    8   if[ ++ I6 < I4] goto 4
    9   Return
```

`f1==f2` returns `True`.

Now, do

```
f5 = Compile[{{L, _Integer}}, Block[{t = 0.},
        Do[t = Sin[i*j], {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}]; t]];
f6 = Compile[{{L, _Integer}}, Block[{t = 0.},
        Do[t = Sin[.45], {i, 1, 2 L}, {j, 1, i}]; t]];
CompilePrint[f5]
CompilePrint[f6]
```

I won't show the full listings, but in the first there is a line `R3 = Sin[ R1]` while in the second there is an assignment to a register `R1 = 0.43496553411123023` (which, however, is reassigned in the innermost part of the loop by `R2 = R1`; perhaps if we output to C this will be optimized by gcc eventually).

So, in these very simple cases, uncompiled `Do` just blindly executes the body without inspecting it, while `Compile` does do various simple optimizations (in addition to outputing byte code). While here I am choosing examples that exaggerate how literally `Do` interprets its argument, this kind of thing partly explains the large speedup after compiling.

As for the [huge speedup in Mike Bantegui's question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853928/more-efficient-way-of-calculating-this-recurrence-relation-in-mathematica/6865423#6865423), I think the speedup in such simple problems (just looping and multiplying things) is because there is no reason that automatically produced C code can't be optimized by the compiler to get things running as fast as possible. The C code produced is too hard to understand for me, but the bytecode is readable and I don't think that there is anything all that wasteful. So it is not that shocking that it is so fast when compiled to C. Using built-in functions shouldn't be any faster than that, since there shouldn't be any difference in the algorithm (if there is, the `Do` loop shouldn't have been written that way).

All this should be checked case by case, of course. In my experience, `Do` loops usually are the fastest way to go for this kind of operation. However, compilation has its limits: if you are producing large objects and trying to pass them around between two compiled functions (as arguments), the bottleneck can be this transfer. One solution is to simply put everything into one giant function and compile that; this ends up being harder and harder to do (you are forced to write C in mma, so to speak). Or you can try compiling the individual functions and using `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}]` in the `Compile`. Things can get tricky very fast, though.

But this is getting too long.